# File with the extension of ".ehi" content is not readable

Tags: file, http

Has anyone encountered a file that has an extension of ".ehi" before?

If I open it using Wordpad, its contents are not readable strings.

[image: Wordpad]

What app should I use in order to open this file type?

Comment: If you down vote - please leave a comment as to why. I'm not a passerby here, I am actually trying to learn something here. An abstract downvote does not help me learn anything other then the fact that the downvoter did not take the time to explain why this was done. When I downvote - I explain why

Answer (score 1):

### What is an EHI file?

> Config file used by HTTP Injector, an Android app used to modify
>   requests and access blocked websites behind firewall with SSH support
>   and proxy server; contains settings that configure HTTP Injector,
>   which includes server login credentials and security/locking
>   information.

Based on this information, it makes sense that the data isn't stored in plain text. The credentials are likely encrypted or otherwise stored in an obfuscated format to help prevent unauthorized access.

Source: https://fileinfo.com/extension/ehi